# Azure PaaS Malwre protection using Symantec

Tags: rest, azure, paas, symantec

I want to enable Malware protection/Virus scanning in my PaaS.
For example i have a Web Api for file upload and store the files to Blob staorage. I want to scan the files before store it using symantec. I dint find any article or code for the same.

Thanks in advance,
Subbiah K

Answer (score 0):

Firstable you need to resolve the licensing with Symantec. Once that is resolved you must configure some startup Tasks for your compute instance.

This **Tasks** are intended to run every time the application is started including when the package is deployed and when the instance is destroyed-recreated by azure maintenance or error conditions.

The startup Task purpose should be to copy / install symantec products to be accessible by the cloud service. As I previously say this Task run everytime the package is deployed including instance reconstruction by azure.

Once the symantec product is installed you only need to run the scan each X time, probably this process should be called from a Worker Role.

Create the Task is quite easy , you need to include something like this in the service definition file

```
<Startup>
    <Task commandLine="Startup.cmd" executionContext="limited" taskType="simple" >
        <Environment>
            <Variable name="MyVersionNumber" value="1.0.0.0" />
        </Environment>
    </Task>
</Startup>
```

the **cmd** file is a windows batch file created to call the Symantec product installer. This Will ensure that the product is installed on each instance even after instance recreation or package deployment.

This link goes to Azure documentation with more detailed information

### [How to configure and run startup tasks for a cloud service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-startup-tasks/)

Comment: No Juan, its not possible to run symantec exe in PaaS. Instead we are planning to read blobs from azure VM with symantec endpoint protection and remove the malware if we find anything. Do you have any idea how to read azure message queue inside windows service, Instead of continuously checking message queue i want to trigger the a method inside the service whenever new message is added.